# SQL SUM() being multiplied with COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql

*dictionaries*: id (INT) | title (VARCHAR) | created_at

*dictionary_ratings*: id (INT) | dictionary_id (INT) | rating (TINYINT)

*terms*: id (INT) | dictionary_id (INT)

I have three SQL tables as shown above (simplified). I want to query all dictionaries and add information about the number of terms per each, as well as the calculated rating of each dictionary.

```
SELECT dictionaries.title,
       SUM(dictionary_ratings.rating) AS rating_count,
       COUNT(terms.id) AS term_count
FROM dictionaries
LEFT JOIN dictionary_ratings
    ON dictionaries.id = dictionary_ratings.dictionary_id
LEFT JOIN terms
    ON dictionaries.id = terms.dictionary_id
GROUP BY dictionaries.id
ORDER BY dictionaries.created_at DESC
```

The query above works OK except that it *multiplies* `SUM(dictionary_ratings.rating)` by `COUNT(terms.id)`. So if I have 5 terms associated with a dictionary, and the total rating is 10, it outputs 50 instead of 10.

How do I fix that?

Comment: you got 5 ratings of 10 or what?

Comment: Can you share some input data and the expected output

Comment: Check this query and let us know it is working for you or not. `SELECT dictionaries.title, sub.total_rating AS rating_count, COUNT(terms.id) AS term_count FROM dictionaries LEFT JOIN ( SELECT dictionary_id, SUM(rating) AS total_rating FROM dictionary_ratings GROUP BY dictionary_id ) sub ON dictionaries.id = sub.dictionary_id LEFT JOIN terms ON dictionaries.id = terms.dictionary_id GROUP BY dictionaries.id ORDER BY dictionaries.created_at DESC`

Comment: @NIKUNJKOTHIYA, this worked as expected. Can I ask you to post this as an answer and add some explanation?

Comment: Added some explanation of the query and code of query. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your query for get your expected result and for that your final query looks like :

```
SELECT 
  dictionaries.title, 
  sub.total_rating AS rating_count, 
  COUNT(terms.id) AS term_count 
FROM 
  dictionaries 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
      dictionary_id, 
      SUM(rating) AS total_rating 
    FROM 
      dictionary_ratings 
    GROUP BY 
      dictionary_id
  ) sub ON dictionaries.id = sub.dictionary_id 
  LEFT JOIN terms ON dictionaries.id = terms.dictionary_id 
GROUP BY 
  dictionaries.id 
ORDER BY 
  dictionaries.created_at DESC
```

> 1. Here the first join is between dictionaries table and the result of a
>    subquery, which calculates the total rating for each dictionary by
>    summing the ratings for that dictionary in the dictionary_ratings
>    table and grouping them by dictionary_id.
> 2. The second join is between the dictionaries table and the terms table.
> 3. And finally, the query then groups the results by the dictionaries.id field and orders
>    the results by dictionaries.created_at field in desc order.